# How to change DNS in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: networking

I want to use OpenDNS and I want to set things up using the command line, I thought that I should edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file but the file starts with a comment stating:

> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

So how do I set up OpenDSN in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: You could also consider installing unbound, and using 127.0.0.1 as preferred dns !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkManager is the program which (via the resolvconf utility) inserts address `127.0.1.1` into `resolv.conf`. NM inserts that address if and only if it is configured to start an instance of the dnsmasq program to serve as a local forwarding nameserver. That dnsmasq instance listens for queries at address `127.0.1.1`.

If you do not want to use a local forwarding nameserver, then configure NetworkManager so it doesn't start a dnsmasq instance nor inserts that address. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and restart the NetworkManager service.

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

In this mode, NetworkManager updates `/etc/resolv.conf` (still via resolvconf) to include the nameserver addresses NetworkManager has for active connections.

If you want to disable the resolvconf mechanism for updating resolv.conf and just use a static resolv.conf file, do the following.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf  # Delete the symbolic link
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf   # Create static file

# Content of static resolv.conf
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 208.67.220.222
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is perfect but to restart the network-manager you have to type this:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: The answer indeed perfect *and* includes that same command.